# 1С 8.3. Как в табличном списке выделить похожую запись?

Tags: 1с

Как в табличном списке выделить жирным каждую похожую запись? Записей могут быть бесконечное множество, но выделить нужно последнюю похожую (может быть несколько похожих, в таком случае каждая похожая запись выделяется жирным).

Например, есть такая табличная запись:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По логике должна выделяться третья (т.к. данная запись в этой строке встречается последний раз) и пятая запись (т.к. данная запись в этой строке встречается последний раз).

Массив данного списка номенклатуры: Товары.

Вывод списка и примерное "условие":

```
Для каждого ТоварыЧасть Из Товары Цикл
Если УсловиеВыполнено=1 Тогда
            СтрокаТЧ.Шрифт = Новый Шрифт(СтрокаТЧ.Шрифт,,,Истина);
        КонецЕсли;
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: Укажите какая используется конфигурация, и какие "формы"

Comment: @santavital
Используется конфигурация Альфа Авто 5. Форма документа (Документ Заказ-наряд)

Comment: Обычные формы или управляемые ?

Comment: @santavital управляемые

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о табличной части документа:

1. Добавить в Табличную часть дополнительную колонку (можно сделать её невидимой)
2. Заполнить дополнительную колонку: 1 - жирный, 0 - обычный
3. В настройках формы выставить Условное оформление для колонки Номенклатура, вида (ТЧ.ДопКолонка = 1) ~~> Шрифт Жирный